# Erlang aborts with sasl application_start_failure

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, sasl

I cross compiled erlang for arm system.
Later, installed Erlang into target as bellow:

```
./Install -sasl <ERL_ROOT>
```

When I check the Erlang on the target getting bellow error:

```
$ erl
Erlang:
=INFO REPORT==== 1-Jan-2015::19:30:44 ===
    application: sasl
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{sasl,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {undef,
                         [{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]},
                          {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                              [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                               {line,273}]}]}}}}
    type: permanent
Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1> {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,
"{application_start_failure,sasl,{bad_return,{{sasl,start,[normal,[]]},
{'EXIT',{undef,[{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},
{line,273}]}]}}}}}"}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Kernel pid terminated (application_controller)
 ({application_start_failure,sasl,
  {bad_return,
   {{sasl,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{f
```

Does anyone know about this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions before adding them!

Comment: Actually, it's the startup message from rabbitmq-server, it seems tags are proper.

Comment: I've also encountered this problem when I try to start rabbitmq-server in docker container. I'm looking for a solution for this. Here should be a solution for it: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/rabbitmq-server

Answer (score 0):

This part of the error message:

```
{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,273}]}
```

shows the place where the error is found. If you loo at the code of application_master.erl you find:

```
start_it_old(Tag, From, Type, ApplData) ->
    {M,A} = ApplData#appl_data.mod,
```

----> the line where the error message is built

```
    case catch M:start(Type, A) of
    {ok, Pid} ->
        link(Pid),
        From ! {Tag, {ok, self()}},
        loop_it(From, Pid, M, []);
    {ok, Pid, AppState} ->
        link(Pid),
        From ! {Tag, {ok, self()}},
        loop_it(From, Pid, M, AppState);
    {'EXIT', normal} ->
        From ! {Tag, {error, {{'EXIT',normal},{M,start,[Type,A]}}}};
    {error, Reason} ->
        From ! {Tag, {error, {Reason, {M,start,[Type,A]}}}};
```

----> the case statement which manages the result

```
    Other ->
        From ! {Tag, {error, {bad_return,{{M,start,[Type,A]},Other}}}}
    end.
```

so you know the the result of the evaluation of `M:start(Type,A)` has returned `{'EXIT',{undef,[{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]}`. This means that the VM is not able to locate the file sasl.beam. So either it does not exist (the erlang libraries compilation is not completed) or something is wrong in the path (the file should be at *"Installation_Path/../lib/sasl-x.y/ebin/sasl.beam"*